# C++ Can't call tskill inside with system call

Tags: c++, system

I can't call taskkill or tskill inside VC++ with system i don't know any alternatives, i have tried writing a .bat file and trying calling tskill, that dind't work either.

```
system("tskill example");
system("dins.bat");
```

they don't work.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. I also recommend reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: What i don't knowis where to put all the callback functions with handles in my Vc++ prog, for example to a button which has this code:        

private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {}

Comment: @Tasos: is that C++/CLI? Sorry, I am unable to help. I suggest you to do a search, or, if you don't find anything relevant, post it as a new question.